# Woocommerce price sorting not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Almost all the guides to implement price sorting on woocommerce site are the same. I've tried two main ways. 1st - hooked up my query args from functions.php like this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'my_custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');

function my_custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
    if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
      if($_GET['sort_by'] == 'by_rating'){        
        $args['meta_key'] = '_wc_average_rating';
      } else if($_GET['sort_by'] == 'by_price') {
        $args['meta_key'] = '_price';
      }
      $args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
      $args['order'] = strtoupper($_GET['sort']);  
    }
    return $args;
}
```

var_dump shows that it has been catched:

```
array(3) { ["orderby"]=> string(14) "meta_value_num" ["order"]=> string(4) "DESC" ["meta_key"]=> string(6) "_price" }
```

But products are still sorted by default woocommerce setting (price, asc).

Then i implemented my filter plugin (which is working pretty well) and tried to add this sorting query to it.

```
class My_blah_blah_filter {
  public static $instance;
  public $productquery;
  public static function init() {
    if ( is_null( self::$instance ) ) {
      self::$instance = new My_blah_blah_filter ();
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }
  private function __construct() {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', [ $this, 'filter_by_current_range' ] );
  }

  public function filter_by_current_range( $query ) {

    $this->productquery = $query;
    $query->set('tax_query', $this->get_tax_query());

    if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
      if($_GET['sort_by'] == 'by_rating'){
        $query->set('meta_key', '_wc_average_rating');
      } else if($_GET['sort_by'] == 'by_price') {
        $query->set('meta_key', '_price');
      } else {
        $query->set('meta_key', '_price');
      }
      $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
      $query->set('order', strtoupper($_GET['sort']));  
    }
  }

  public function get_tax_query() {

    // pa_space-overall
    $tax_query = [];
    if( isset( $_GET['max_so'] ) && isset( $_GET['min_so'] ) ) {
      $terms = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => 'pa_space-overall',
      ]);
      $rlt = [];
      foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        if( (int) $term->name <= (int) $_GET['max_so'] && (int) $term->name >= (int) $_GET['min_so'] ) {
          $rlt[] = $term->term_id;
        }
      }

      $tax_query = [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
          'taxonomy' => 'pa_space-overall',
          'terms' => $rlt,
          'operator' => 'IN',
        ],
      ];
    }
    if( isset( $this->productquery->tax_query ) ) {
      $tax_query = array_merge( $this->productquery->query_vars['tax_query'], $tax_query );
    }

    return $tax_query;
}
```

Some stuff here is hardcoded, but its not the case, its working. But not the ordering. Its still being catched, added to query, but order is default anyways (price, asc - from woocommerce settings)
The only plugin except woocommerce - is advanced custom fields, which has nothing to do with it.

Cant find any solution anywhere else. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.
Sorry for poor english or not-perfectly-formatted code

Comment: Have you tried wp_query? I'm not here to plug my site. but I did something similar to  [this](http://reydennalasa.com/get-all-products-under-a-category/). my link is how you sort it by category , but you could tweak my query to also be available to display by price.